# how link with -lnfc in CLion?

Tags: c, cmake, clion, lib-nfc

I found my problem in [issues](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/issues/423), but I don't know how link in CLion

> you need to link with -lnfc

I using `gcc -o readerpnv main.c -lnfc`, but honestly I don't like this way.

I try add `-lnfc` to build options, he wrote `Unknown argument -lnfc`

[versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ISmS.png)

P.S. I'm new in C, please write in more detail, thanks

Comment: You need to modify the `CMakeLists.txt` file that defines the executable target. There you need to add a [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) command to list the libraries you want to link with.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `target_link_libraries(nfcio -lnfc)` `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "nfcio" which is not built by this
  project.`

Comment: What does your `add_executable` command look like? What is the target name defined by the `add_executable` command?

Comment: I recommend you spend some time with [this CMake tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html), as well as [the general documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/index.html).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you, I add `target_link_libraries` before `add_executable` and his working